# Добавлять столбец через цикл

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных

Ребята очень нужна помощь . Друг помог написать за 5 минут код но я вижу что он очень прям корявый но направление вроде правильное ... Как можно при выборе даты в форме выводить через цикл конкретное количество столбиков ? По принципу если в этом месяце 31 день то показывается 31 столбик и записывается в нем же название дней недели ,если 28 например то 28 столбиков и т.д. **ОЧЕНЬ НУЖНА ПОМОЩЬ**  ( 
1.пн|2.вт|3.ср|4.чт|5.пт|6.сб|7.вс|8.пн|9.вт|10.ср|11.чт| и т.д.)

**вот тот самый недокод **

```
<?php
        $number_days = "28"; // колличество дней минимум
$tablheader = "<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Статус</td><td>---</td></tr>"; // построение таблицы
if (isset($_POST['dateList'])) {
$i = 1; // добавление + одного столбца в таблицу
while($i++ < $number_days){
    $header = $tablheader.($i++);
}
$days = date ("D"); // формат вывода в днях пн,вт...
$number_alldays = "31";// колличество дней максимум
while($i <= '31') {
    if($i <= $number_alldays ){
      $amount_of_days = $days.$header(   );
    }else{ $amount_of_days = $days.'---' };
    echo "<tr><td>Имя</td><td>Статус</td><td>'.$header.'</td></tr>" //выводить результат заданое колличество дней по нумерации и названию 
}

$table_str.= ($tablheader);
return $table_str;

?>
```

**здесь выбирать дату**

```
    <legend><b>Введите любую дату</b></legend>
<form method="POST">
<input type="date" name="dateList" list="dateList">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
<datalist id="dateList">
<option value="2018-12-01" label="">
<option value="2018-02-01" label="">
<option value="2018-04-01" label="">
</datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: думаю тут стоит брать время unix timestamp и в цикле ему добавлять день, пока месяц не станет другим.

Comment: там похожее и написано , добавляет инкрементом

Comment: только по коду я так понял куча ошибок ((

Comment: По коду вообще ничего не понятно если честно. И не вижу вообще привязки к дней к месяцу, всегда 31

Comment: Здесь выбирается дата... if (isset($_POST['dateList']))